# Any issues with LightSwitch Beta 2 and Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

Just about ready to move to LightSwitch Beta 2 and was wondering if anyone ran into any issues with installing Silverlight 5 Beta after that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a common problem with the Toolkit because Microsoft hasn't released one specifically for Silverlight 5. That's all I've heard of though, if your toying around go ahead and try it, if you are doing something professionally I'd wait until the beta is over and they release.